# No consigo cargar la imagen en el store

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo un formulario en el que pido los datos de un nuevo usuario, teniendo entre sus variables una llamada "foto", en la cual almaceno una imagen del usuario.

La migración del usuario:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('provincia')->nullable();
            $table->string('localidad')->nullable();
            $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
            $table->string('telefono');
            $table->string('dni')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('vehiculo')->default(false);
            $table->string('foto')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('activado')->default(false); // Se marca aqui como falso y ya se pone automaticamente así al hacer el formulario.
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

El formulario en el que creo el usuario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Registrarse') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="second_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Apellidos') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="second_name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('second_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="second_name" value="{{ old('second_name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('second_name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('second_name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="provincia" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Provincia') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="provincia" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('provincia') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="provincia" value="{{ old('provincia') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('provincia'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('provincia') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="localidad" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Ciudad') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="localidad" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('localidad') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="localidad" value="{{ old('localidad') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('localidad'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('localidad') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="direccion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Direccion') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="direccion" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('direccion') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="direccion" value="{{ old('direccion') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('direccion'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('direccion') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Telefono') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('telefono') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('telefono'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('telefono') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dni" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('DNI') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="dni" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('dni') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="dni" value="{{ old('dni') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('dni'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('dni') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dni" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Foto de usuario</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="foto" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('foto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="foto" value="{{ old('foto') }}" />

                                @if ($errors->has('foto'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="vehiculo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">¿Tiene usted algun vehiculo?</label>
                            Si<input type="radio" name="vehiculo" value=1 />
                            No<input type="radio" name="vehiculo" value=0 checked />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Correo Electronico') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirmar Contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Registrarse') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

El metodo con el que almaceno en la base de datos el nuevo usuario:

```
use App\Helper;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

protected function create(array $data){
        request()->file($data['foto'])->store('fotos');
        $foto=request()->file($key)->hashName();
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'second_name' => $data['second_name'],
            'provincia' => $data['provincia'],
            'localidad' => $data['localidad'],
            'direccion' => $data['direccion'],
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'vehiculo' => $data['vehiculo'],
            'dni' => $data['dni'],
            'foto' => $foto,
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Se supone que tras eso puedo utilizar para un formulario una imagen y esta se copiara en "storage\app\public\fotos", pero me encuentro con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estare haciendo mal?

Comment: Me parece que hace falta el `enctype` al formulario, es decir `enctype="multipart/form-data"` , aparte donde hace el llamado al método , ¿Se trata de un controlador? ¿un repositorio ? por qué un `array` y no un `Request`?

Comment: Es array en vez de request porque así es como viene de forma predeterminada en el archivo RegisterController. De hecho, es el tipico formulario con el que la gente se crea una cuenta de usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Al final logre arreglarlo (aunque ha costado un infierno de pruebas fallidas). Lo que he hecho es que he quitado la opción de adjuntar una imagen en el formulario, haciendo que el usuario empiece con una imagen predeterminada tras registrarse, luego creo un segundo formulario en el que permito que el usuario se modifique la imagen y luego dicho formulario lo proceso en UserController:

```
public function nuevaImagen(Request $request){
    $normas=['foto'=>'required|image'];
    $mensajes=[
        'foto.required'=>'La imagen es obligatoria',
        'foto.image'=>'Error en el formato'
    ];

    $validez=Validator::make($request->all(),$normas,$mensajes);
    if($validez->fails())
        return back()->withErrors($validez);
    else{
        $nombre=str_random(30).'-'.$request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('foto')->move('storage',$nombre);
        $usuario=auth()->user();
        $usuario->foto=$nombre;
        $usuario->save();
        return back()->with('message',['success','La nueva foto se ha asignado correctamente']);
    }
}
```

Ademas, es más coherente con el modo que funcionan muchas paginas web, las cuales suelen permitir que vayas cambiandote la imagen a capricho.